# Google Maps JavaScript API　が表示されない

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps JavaScript APIでサイト内に地図を表示させたいのですが、基本認証がかかっているサイトでは表示できないのでしょうか？
一瞬表示されるのですが、「エラーが発生しました」となり、エラーコンソールに「Your site URL to be authorized」と出ます。

どうかお力添えの程よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 1):

google maps apiは一般公開サイトにおいてはフリーで使えるものなので、認証をかけたときにはそういった症状になる可能性があります
https://developers.google.com/maps/support/availability?hl=ja

Comment: やはり誰もが閲覧できる状況でないと表示できないのですね。
開発者ライセンスなどを利用すれば開発環境下（非公開サイト）でも扱えるようです。